# What is the correct approach to create a custom GoTo Definition behavior in VS Code extension?

Tags: typescript, programming-languages, vscode-extensions, go-to-definition

I am creating a VS Code extension that supports a small proprietary language. One of the minimal requirements for it is to have a "Go To Definition" functionality for procedures only. Being very new to JavaScript/TypeScript i'm struggling with using VSCode's API to actually solve the problem.

I have a grasp on what is required to make a VS Code extension, i.e the purpose of package.json, activate function in extesnion.ts and a general understanding of TypeScript (coming from Python). I have tried to refer to some open-source code that implements a much more advanced version of my extension ([vscode-go](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go)), but the code there is overwhelming to go through as a TS beginner.

Essentially my question boils down to: Is there a simple way (may be an abstract set of steps?) to implement a very basic "go-to function definition within the same file" behavior, without resorting to creating a custom language server?

Comment: If you have access to the source code of the compiler, do make a language server out of it (and ignore the answer below). Don't do the same parsing tasks multiple times as you can easily create inconsistency on language syntax support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide a `Go To Definition` feature, just like other extensions, you just have to register and implement a `DefinitionProvider`.

You don’t need a language server for that, nor any complex tooling. A simple lazy parser would work just fine :-).

I’ve made a Pascal (https://github.com/alefragnani/vscode-language-pascal) extension that provides some of these features, and don’t use a Language Server. I’m using global/ctags to parse and generate tags for the sources. Then I load and parse its output to identify the symbols.

You are free to take a look (https://github.com/alefragnani/vscode-language-pascal/blob/master/src/providers/definitionProvider.ts). The source code is open and fairly simple, as it was one of the first extensions that I have developed.

Hope this helps